# Sort an array by value

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
array = ["git-hw-abcd", "svn-hw", "svn-hw-design","git-hw"]
```

If I do array.sort I would basically get an ascending sort like this

```
["git-hw", "git-hw-abcd", "svn-hw", "svn-hw-design"]
```

Would like to sort the array by the values `"svn-hw"` and `"git-hw"` to appear as the first and second elements of the array so that I would get:

[ "svn-hw","git-hw",... then the rest of the values]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: write a block for your sort. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: What exact sort criteria do you want? Why does `git-hw-abcd` appear before `svn-hw-design`?

Comment: How does a four-element array become a three-element array by sort?

Comment: Edited my post. There was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
* sorting on length(as sort criteria is not specified)

["git-hw-abcd", "svn-hw", "svn-hw-design","git-hw"].sort{|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}
```

It returns

```
["git-hw", "svn-hw", "git-hw-abcd", "svn-hw-design"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`array.sort{|a,b|  a.split("-h")[1]<=>b.split("-h")[1]}`

this is what you want

@Hivltg

try the length order using this :`array= [ "svn-hw", "git-hw-abcd","git-hw", "svn-hw-design", "git-hw-bassics"]`

you will find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response but split wouldn't work effeciently as it would throw an error if "-" is not present in the array.

Comment: If your array is not as a fixed pattern ,then there is no way to perfectly solve your problem.

Comment: And just order by length won't affect when there is a string like 'xxx-hw-aaaaaaaaaaaaaa',it should before 'xxx-hw-b', am I right? or you do mean 'order by length'

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how you're ordering, but here's an example of using a block to sort

```
array.sort{|a,b| a[4..-1] <=> b[4..-1]}
```